# Continuous function with open preimmage

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let     $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous function where $X, Y$ are topological spaces. Let $U\subset Y$ such that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$, then does it mean that $U\subset Y$ is open in $Y$? I guess no, because if we consider the constant function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ defined by $f(x) = y_0$, for $y_0$ is fixed in $Y$. Then $f$ is always continuous, and $f^{-1}(U)$ is either the empty set of $X$, so it always open in $X$ for also non open $U$.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: @JacobZhang The question is "is every continuous map a quotient map?"

Answer (score 1):

In general it is false that given a continuous function $f: X \to Y$ and $f^{-1}(U) \subseteq X$ open that $U \subseteq Y$ is open. There are times in which this does hold however, and in that case $f$ would be called a $\textit{quotient mapping}$, and $Y$ a quotient space.

A good example of a quotient map is the function 
$$f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$$
given by $f(x)=(cos(2 \pi x), sin(2 \pi x))$, which shows that the circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ may be thought of as a quotient of the interval $[0,1]$ (an alternative way to think of the image $f([0,1])$ is as the set $[0,1]/\sim$, where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation on $[0,1]$ given by $a \sim b$ if and only if $a=b$ or $a=0$ and $b=1$).

As for your example, given the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology and the map $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=0$, since $\{0\}$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$, the function $f$ is not a quotient map.